# How can I pass an @FormParam to a RESTful service from another method?

Tags: java, web-services, rest

**DISCLAIMER:** I did search exhaustively for an answer to this question, and yes, I did find this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315728/how-to-send-parameters-as-formparam-to-webservice .  But firstly, that question is asking about Javascript, while I am asking about Java, and secondly, it has no answers anyway.  So on to the question...

With RESTful services, passing `@QueryParam`s into an `@GET` service is fairly easy, as you can simply append variables name/value pairs to a URL and use it to hit the server from within the program.  Is there a way to do this with `@FormParam`s as well?

For example, let's say I have the following RESTful service:

```
@POST
@Produces("application/xml")
@Path("/processInfo")
public String processInfo(@FormParam("userId") String userId,
                          @FormParam("deviceId") String deviceId,
                          @FormParam("comments") String comments) {
    /*
     * Process stuff and return
     */
}
```

... and let's say I also have another method somewhere else in my program like this:

```
public void updateValues(String comments) {

    String userId = getUserId();
    String deviceId = getDeviceId();

    /*
     * Send the information to the /processInfo service
     */

}
```

How can I perform the commented out action in the second method?

**NOTE:** Assume these methods are not in the same class or package.  Also assume that the RESTful service is hosted on a *different* server than the machine you are running your method from.  As such, you *must* access the method and pass the values in in a RESTful way.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using @FormParam you can bind form parameters to a variable.You can find a sample [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-formparam-example/).

Secondly ,In order to call rest service internally form your java method code you will have to use jersey client.Example code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312421/error-on-creating-rest-client-using-jersey).

You can pass form parameters using jersey client form as follows.

Create form

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource service = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/api").build());

Form f = new Form();    
f.add("userId", "foo");    
f.add("deviceId", "bar");    
f.add("comments", "Device");
```

pass it to Restful method.

```
service.path("processInfo").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(String.class,f);
```

[reference](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html#d4e644)

Comment: You can pass form parameters like this,Use com.sun.jersey.api.representation.Form as follows.
    Form f = new Form();
    f.add("userId", "foo");
    f.add("deviceId", "bar");
    f.add("comments", "Device");
    // Fluent interfaces
    service.path("processInfo").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(String.class,f);

Comment: That's great!  Could you add that to your answer and explain the last line a bit more?  This one: `service.path("processInfo").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(String.class,‌​f)`  Then I'll accept. :)

Comment: Specifically, what is the `service` object that you're invoking `path()` on?